# "Cat" into multiple files using brace expansion

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am quite new to bash and trying to type some text into multiple files with a single command using brace expansion.

I tried: `cat > file_{1..100}` to write into 100 files some text that I will type in the terminal. I get the following error:

`bash: file_{1..100}: ambiguous redirect`

I also tried: `cat > "file_{1..100}"` but that creates a singe file named: `file_{1..100}`.

I tried: `` cat > `file_{1..100}` `` but that gives the error:
`file_1: command not found`

How can I achieve this using brace expansion? Maybe there are other ways using other utilities and/or pipelines. But I want to know if that is possible using only simple brace expansion or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with `cat` alone.  It only writes its output to its standard output, and that single file descriptor can only be associated with a single file.

You can however do it with `tee file_{1..100}`.

You may wish to consider using `tee file_{01..100}` instead, so that the filenames are zero-padded to all have the same width: `file_001, file_002, ...`  This has the advantage that lexicographic order will agree with numerical order, and so `ls`, `*`, etc, will process them in numerical order.  Without this, you have the situation that `file_2` comes after `file_10` in lexicographic order.

Answer (score 3):

target could be only a pipe, not a multiple files.
If you want redirect output to multiple files, use tee

```
cat | tee file_{1..100}
```

Don't forget to check man tee, for example if you want to append to the files, you should add -a option (tee -a file_{1..100})

Comment: There is no point in using `cat` in your example, since `tee` is reading from stdin anyway.

Answer (score -1):

This types the `string` or `text` into `file{1..4}`

```
echo "hello you just knew me by kruz" > file{1..4}
```

Use to remove them

```
rm file*
```